# How to lightly fade bottom of UIImage and Fade to Blur as scrolling up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, blur, cagradientlayer

I've been working on a `UICollectionView` header as a `UICollectionReusableView` and I'm trying to achieve 1) a lightly bottom faded image and 2) as the user scrolled up the image would blur.

I'm essentially looking at Apple's Music app, and it's an artist profile view which is in my opinion a great looking app.

1. Lightly faded bottom
2. Scrolling up blur

[image: Blurred Image:]
[image: As the user scrolls up:]

My starting point works however I'd like to have a more subtle bottom fade, then once I have that nailed, think about blurring with scrolling..

Code where applying `CAGradientLayer`:

```
UIImageView *imageView;
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:header.bounds];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.guest.profilePic];
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];

CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = imageView.bounds;

UIColor *transWhiteColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.25];
UIColor *endColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   (id)[transWhiteColor CGColor],
                   (id)[endColor CGColor],
                   nil];

[imageView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
[header addSubview:imageView];
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!